# Statistical Significance test for difference in FScore

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, statistical-significance, natural-language

For a classification task, I have developed two methods and FScore(harmonic mean of precision and recall) of both the classes serves as the performance criteria. How can I check whether the difference between the performance of the two systems is statistically significant or not.

For eg. I was reading [a paper](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P06/P06-1014.pdf) by Navigli and in the evaluation he cites that "all the differences between 2 systems are statistically significant (p < 0.01)"

I would like to know how to perform this test of statistical significance.

EDIT : No clue is there regarding which test is been talked about. Is there some standard test used in NLP community? (the work is related to Natural Language Processing)

Comment: What makes you think "*the test he used is called p-test*" - there's no indication in the text near the phrase "*all the differences between*" to suggest what test was used; only a p-value is quoted. When you say 'fscore' what are you referring to?

Comment: Best to email the author directly.

Comment: Have you received any answer? I'm actually having the same problem here...

Comment: @JoachimBingel : No. I haven't got any definite answer yet.